# logo and navigation over orbit photo slideshow

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have used Bootstrap extensively but am now trying to learn Foundation. There is a template I'm working on but I don't know how to do this.

I would like to have a logo and navigation over the orbit photo slideshow, with a transparent black background.

The difficulty it's not on the transparent background, but in **how to place the logo and navigation above the images**.

Attached is a mockup of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using z-index?
[Here's a great article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) that explains how to use it.